# Ubuntu virtual machine very slow boot time

Tags: boot, 16.04, virtualbox, performance, swap

I have a VM running Ubuntu 16.04 on a Windows 7 host. It used to start up very quickly, but ever since I re-partitioned the disk to allow for more space using GParted, it takes about a minute to get to the login screen once I start the vm from virtual box. [I have given a large amount of swap space.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IGdK.png)

In my Virtual Box settings under **Storage > Controller: IDE** the disk is currently marked 'Empty', but all my data loads just fine when it does eventually boot. If I change this .iso to the ubuntu.iso, it is then that I do not have my data available. What else can I do to diagnose the problem / does anyone know what can be done?

```
$ sudo blkid
 /dev/sda1: UUID="8563..." TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="938..-01"
 /dev/sda5: UUID="6696..." TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="938..-05"
```

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
<file system><mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
 / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
 UUID="8563..."                   /         ext4   errors=remount-ro     0 1
 swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
 UUID="0dd5..."                   none      swap   sw     0 0
```

```
$free -h 
       total    used    free    shared    buff/cache    available
Mem:   9.8G     1.4G    3.6G    42M       4.8G          8.0G
Swap:  0B       0B      0B
```

```
$ swapon
$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from the comments...

*Edit your question to include the terminal output of `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `free -h` and `swapon`.*

Edit `/etc/fstab` to make the UUID match the one from blkid.

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab
```

**Change this:**

```
UUID=0dd5...   none   swap    sw    0   0
```

**To this:**

```
UUID=6696...   none   swap    sw    0   0
```

**Then:**

`sudo swapon -a` # to turn on swap

`free -h`        # to see memory and swap

`sudo swapon`    # to see swap partition info

Comment: 1000 thank you's for this @heynnema. How can this be prevented when partitioning in the future?

Comment: @DavidAnekstein just remember that if you delete/recreate your swap partition, that the UUID will change, and you must edit /etc/fstab.