# swapon --show is empty

Tags: partitioning, mount, swap

I was given a VM to use for a class, and it was far too small. I extended the main HD by 100 GB to give me some breathing room. In the process, I had to remove and re-add the swap partition. The assignment is about forensics, and has nothing to do with administering the system (fyi).

Boot time was slow, so I found a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929263/ubuntu-virtual-machine-very-slow-boot-time); however, I don't really know what I'm doing with this. My `sudo swapon --show` command was empty. The output of the first command was:

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/sr0: UUID="2020-01-13-11-26-32-82" LABEL="VBox_GAs_6.1.2" TYPE="iso9660"
/dev/sda1: UUID="48d21be0-266d-412f-94c2-47eb9bdfcb6e" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="59d4415c-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="525383e5-fea2-4b7d-bd81-028fd6f55e88" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="59d4415c-05"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/fd0: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="C4B1-CDCF" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
```

and the second:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=48d21be0-266d-412f-94c2-47eb9bdfcb6e /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=ab7cc7d6-77e0-444f-982d-bb64502305b9 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

My guess is that swap is pointing to an old drive `ab7cc...` and needs to point to `52538...` but I'm hesitant to muck around with this as I don't really know what it is.

**Is my swap set up correctly?** If yes, what else can I check for a "slow boot time"

Comment: Got impatient... the answer is to edit /etc/fstab to match the output of blkid. I will answer my own question if no one else does.

Comment: You have to edit your swap UUID in `/etc/genfstab`. Replace it with the UUID given by the command `sudo blkid`.

Comment: Sorry, did not see that your solved your problem by your own...

Comment: No worries! confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're absolutely correct. There's a mismatch between UUIDs. This occurred because of the re-creation of the swap partition. You executed the correct commands to determine this.

`free -h` # show a little more data

`sudo blkid` # show UUIDs

`cat /etc/fstab` # show fstab

`sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` # edit fstab

In /etc/fstab...

Change:

```
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=ab7cc7d6-77e0-444f-982d-bb64502305b9 none    swap    sw     0 0
```

To:

```
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=525383e5-fea2-4b7d-bd81-028fd6f55e88 none    swap    sw     0 0
```

Then `reboot` and it should boot a lot faster, as it won't be waiting for a non-existent swap partition.